# Python and java applications throw IOError at the same time

Tags: java, python

I have been experiencing weird behaviour of my scripts lately. I have a script in python, which accepts requests through `TCP/IP` and copies files, starts/stops `JAVA` applications and so on.

Once a time, when command which has to recreate a directory arrives, both, python AND all `JAVA` application crashes with `IOError`.

What I don't understand is, that during copying from A to B, it throws error that certain file doesn't exist in **destination (B)** - of course! Thats why I want to copy it there!

At the same time, all java application crash too, with `IOException`.

Here are stack traces:

PYTHON

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hosting/Executable.py", line 35, in copyCachedExec
    copy_tree(path + "/server", target)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dir_util.py", line 163, in copy_tree
    verbose=verbose, dry_run=dry_run))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dir_util.py", line 167, in copy_tree
    dry_run=dry_run)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/file_util.py", line 148, in copy_file
    _copy_file_contents(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/file_util.py", line 44, in _copy_file_contents
    fdst = open(dst, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/hosting/servers/22842/mods/Factorization-0.7.21.jar'
```

JAVA

```
2013-10-20 17:44:19 [SEVERE] null
java.io.IOException: Input/output error
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:272)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.console.ConsoleReader$1.read(ConsoleReader.java:167)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:267)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:204)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readCharacter(ConsoleReader.java:995)
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:1167)
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R3.ThreadCommandReader.run(ThreadCommandReader.java:31)
```

P.S.: The destination directory is removed before the copying starts.

EDIT:
I am copying a directory tree **x**

```
/home/hosting/files/x/server.jar

/home/hosting/files/x/Factorization-0.7.21.jar

/home/hosting/files/x/other_files
```

to another directory `/home/hosting/servers/22842`, which exists

Comment: `No such file or directory: '/home/hosting/servers/22842/mods/Factorization-0.7.21.jar'`

Comment: Well, and the `mods` subdirectory? Does that exist, too?

Comment: It doesn't exist in the destination, since it should be copied as part of the tree, shouldn't it?

Comment: No, unless you're using `shutil.copytree()`. How exactly are you copying the tree?

Comment: Just noticed we don't use shutil's copytree, but distutil's copy_tree, hope it will work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your P.S. explains the problem.

```
open(dst, 'wb') # dst='/home/hosting/servers/22842/mods/Factorization-0.7.21.jar'
```

requires the path `/home/hosting/servers/22842/mods/` to be present. When using `open()` to create a file, `IOError` is raised if any part of the path is missing.

Comment: That would be both, awesome, since it would resolve the problem, but very sad, because I copy directory that includes /mods/Factorization-0.7.21.jar. More in question, I edited it.